# How to retrieve single value from $stmt->get_result()

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm trying to get a `1` or a `0` from the result, but how do I retrieve it and use it as a simple variable to compare with other variable? I want to use my variable `$result_1` and check if it has the value of `1` or `0`.

```
//
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT status FROM todo WHERE id=?");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
$stmt->execute();
$result_1 = $stmt->get_result();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php

In the examples it states that `get_result()` returns a result set. Which is basically a container for all the rows that came back. They can be aquired by the following procedure.

`$result = $stmt->get_result();
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$result_1 = $row['status'];`

My example assumes that data came back.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT `status` FROM `todo` WHERE `id` = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
$stmt->execute();
$result_1 = $stmt->get_result();

while($row = $result_1->fetch_assoc()) {
    //do something
    echo row['status'];
}
```